# why are entitymanagers in separate threads from the same entitymanagerfactory only updated on entitymanager.close()

Tags: java, multithreading, jpa, entitymanager

I have an application managed JPA set up (first time i have used JPA).

I have one reader thread and one writer thread.

The reader creates and closes entity managers per query or transaction.

The writer thread creates one entity manager and reads of a blocking queue so that the it knows all the managed entities as I have a lot of one to many/parent child relationships that if I have cascade types on results in duplicate exception (com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException), or without cascading results in  transient entity exceptions (i.e entitymanager not aware of parent entities) if I open and close the entity manager per entity write.

The issues I have is that if I persist via the db writer thread, then query via a sql query the db reader thread returns null even though the entity is persisted in the  database (mysql) and both entity managers are created from the same entity manager factory. If I close the entity manager in the db writer thread after each insert, then the reader thread does become aware of the inserted entity, but then the writer is not aware of the previously inserted parent entities and throws MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException. I believe that closing the entitymanager seems to detach all entities and clear the persistence context of the entity manager, but if I do this in a method via the @PostPersist annotation it does not seem to help making any of the entitymanagers created in the reader thread aware of the entities inserted by the single entitymanager in writer thread.

If there any way to make the entity managers created in the reader thread aware of the inserts/updates done by the writer thread? (tried evict all, without much luck). It is quite a big changed to move to EJB's and a container managed JPA set up, I believe I would also have to run apache on the server to manage the EJB.

I have tried a few things without much luck

- detaching entity on persist
- evicting entity on persist
- cascading persistence of parent entities
- refreshing entity on persist
- overriding equals and hashcode of entity
- Bypassing the cache on read

Entity Manager Factory

```
    Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();

    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", createMode);
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", ConfigUtil.combined().getString("db.driver"));
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", ConfigUtil.combined().getString("db.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.url", ConfigUtil.combined().getString("db.url"));
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.username", ConfigUtil.combined().getString("db.username"));
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.password", ConfigUtil.combined().getString("db.password"));
    properties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");

    try {
        PersistUtilHelper emh = new PersistUtilHelper(properties);
```

Example Entity

```
public abstract class EntityBase implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", length = 16, updatable = false, nullable = false)
public UUID getId() {
    ensureId();
    return id;
}

@Version
private Long version;

public Long getVersion() {
    return version;
}

public void setVersion(Long version) {
    this.version = version;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    // generated by IDEA
    if (this == o)
        return true;
    if (!(o instanceof EntityBase))
        return false;
    EntityBase that = (EntityBase) o;
    return id.equals(that.id);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    ensureId();
    return id.hashCode();
}

// JPA
protected EntityBase() {
}

protected void setId(UUID id) {
    this.id = id;
}

private void ensureId() {
    if (id == null)
        id = UUID.randomUUID();
}

private UUID id;
}




@Entity
@Table(name = "listing", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "base", "quote",     "prompt" }),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "base", "quote" }) })
public class Listing extends EntityBase {

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
//@Column(unique = true)
public Asset getBase() {
    return base;
}

@PostPersist
private void postPersist() {
    //  PersistUtil.clear();
    //  PersistUtil.refresh(this);
    //PersistUtil.merge(this);
    // PersistUtil.close();
    //PersistUtil.evict(this);

}

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
//@Column(unique = true)
public Asset getQuote() {
    return quote;
}

@Nullable
//@Column(unique = true)
public String getPrompt() {
    return prompt;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Listing) {
        Listing listing = (Listing) obj;

        if (!listing.getBase().equals(getBase())) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!listing.getQuote().equals(getQuote())) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getQuote().hashCode() + getBase().hashCode();
}
```

Writer Thread

```
public class DatabaseWriter implements Runnable {
private static final int defaultBatchSize = 20;
private static boolean running = false;
private static boolean shutdown = false;
private static ExecutorService service;
private static FutureTask persitanceTask = null;

 private static BlockingQueue<EntityBase[]> blockingQueue;

 public DatabaseWriter(BlockingQueue<EntityBase[]> blockingqueue) {
    this.blockingQueue = blockingqueue;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    EntityBase[] entities = null;
    boolean persited = true;
    while (!shutdown) {

        try {
            entities = blockingQueue.take();
            for (EntityBase entity : entities)
                PersistUtil.persist(entity);
        }

        catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
        }

    }
    PersistUtilHelper.closeEntityManager();

}
}
```

Sample Read

```
  Listing listing = PersistUtil.queryZeroOne(Listing.class, "select a from Listing a where base=?1     and quote=?2", base, quote);
```

Reader Thread

```
     public static <T> T queryZeroOne(Class<T> resultType, String queryStr, Object... params) {

    try {
        //EntityManager em = createEntityManager();
        final TypedQuery<T> query = PersistUtilHelper.createQuery(queryStr, resultType);
        //query.setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", false);
        //  query.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode", javax.persistence.CacheRetrieveMode.BYPASS);
        //query.setHint("org.hibernate.cacheMode", CacheMode.IGNORE);

        if (params != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                Object param = params[i];
                query.setParameter(i + 1, param); // JPA uses 1-based indexes
            }
        }
        try {
            return query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException x) {
            return null;
        }
    } finally {

        PersistUtilHelper.closeEntityManager();
    }
}
```

Helper Util

```
 public class PersistUtilHelper {

private static EntityManagerFactory emf = null;
private static final ThreadLocal<EntityManager> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<EntityManager>();
private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, EntityManager> entityManagers = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, EntityManager>();

PersistUtilHelper(Map<String, String> properties) {
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("xyz.schema", properties);
}

public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {

    return emf;
}

public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    EntityManager em = threadLocal.get();
    if (em == null || !em.isOpen()) {
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        entityManagers.put(em.toString(), em);
        threadLocal.set(em);
    }
    return em;
}

public static <T> TypedQuery<T> createQuery(String qlString, Class<T> resultClass) {
    getEntityManager().clear();
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(qlString, resultClass);
}

public static Query createQuery(String qlString) {
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(qlString);
}

public static void closeEntityManager() {
    EntityManager em = threadLocal.get();
    if (em != null) {
        entityManagers.remove(em.toString());
        em.close();
        threadLocal.set(null);
    }
}

public static void clearEntityManager() {
    EntityManager em = threadLocal.get();
    if (em != null) {
        em.clear();
    }
}

public static void closeEntityManagerFactory() {
    emf.close();
    emf = null;
}

public static void beginTransaction() {
    getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
}

public static void rollback() {
    getEntityManager().getTransaction().rollback();
}

public static void commit() {
    getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
}

public static void detach(Object entity) {
    Iterator it = entityManagers.values().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        EntityManager em = (EntityManager) it.next();
        if (em != null || em.isOpen())
            em.detach(entity);
    }
}

public static void evict(Object entity) {
    Iterator it = entityManagers.values().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        EntityManager em = (EntityManager) it.next();
        if (em != null || em.isOpen())
            em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evict(entity.getClass(), ((EntityBase) entity).getId());
        //em.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager(SynchronizationType.)

    }
}

public static void merge(Object entity) {
    Iterator it = entityManagers.values().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        EntityManager em = (EntityManager) it.next();
        if (em != null || em.isOpen())
            em.merge(entity);
    }
}

public static void refresh(Object entity) {
    Iterator it = entityManagers.values().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        EntityManager em = (EntityManager) it.next();
        if (em != null || em.isOpen())
            em.refresh(entity);

    }
}

public static boolean isActive() {
    return getEntityManager().getTransaction().isActive();

}

public static boolean isOpen() {
    return emf.isOpen();
}

public static void evictAll() {
    emf.getCache().evictAll();

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no point in your code when you're calling `commit`, don't forget to commit your work when you're done.